# Raspberry Pi as Office Jukebox?

Tags: networking, audio, software-recommendation

I'd like to set up an office jukebox using a Pi. I've found some [decent instructions](http://blog.ziade.org/2012/07/01/a-raspberry-pi-juke-box-how-to/) for a simple implementation, which look good as far as all the audio stuff goes.

My problem is that this requires the files to be on storage connected to the Pi. Is there any piece of software that will allow users to play a file from their own machine via the Pi?

I don't really care about interface, it could be a web interface, or even command line, but some way for people to remotely 'push' a file onto the jukeboxe's queue.

Comment: I have not looked at the specific software you are using for the jukebox, but there are *DNLA* servers and clients available for most common end-user platforms (linux, win, mac, android).  So the Pi would be the server, and any client can use it to play their own stuff.  How that fits into your jukebox scheme, I can't say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just mount their shares on the PI - that's your quickest option:

```
pi@raspberrypi /mnt $ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.107/music -o username=sasha,password=somepassword /mnt/music
pi@raspberrypi /mnt $ ls -la music/
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root        0 May 20  2007 _
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    65536 Dec  2  2007 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Feb 12 23:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root        0 May 20  2007 #2
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root        0 May 20  2007 #4
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root        0 May 20  2007 AAVV
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root        0 May 20  2007 AL
...
```

A better way to organize this would be setting up a media client as mentioned above. [Here is](http://chrisbaume.wordpress.com/2012/06/24/raspberry-pi-upnp-media-player/) a good article on this.